# can only concatenate str (not "bytes") to str

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, byte

```
import socket
import os

user_url = input("Enter url: ")

host_name = user_url.split("/")[2]
mysock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
mysock.connect((host_name, 80))
cmd = 'GET ' + user_url + ' HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n'.encode()
mysock.send(cmd)

while True:
    data = mysock.recv(512)
    if len(data) < 1:
        break
     print(data.decode(),end='\n')

mysock.close()
```

For some reason im gettin this error

> ### Enter url: http://data.pr4e.org/romeo.txt
>
> ```
>  7 mysock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
>  8 mysock.connect((host_name, 80))
>  9 cmd = 'GET ' + user_url + ' HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n'.encode()
>  TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "bytes") to str
> ```

Any ideas what im doing wrong with it?Encoding and decoding seems right to me, and i've trasnfered it using \n before .encode().
This is for a class

Comment: I got the same issue in the same problem! Thank you for the question
https://www.freecodecamp.org/learn/scientific-computing-with-python/python-for-everybody/networking-write-a-web-browser

Answer (score 22):

A `str` is an abstract sequence of Unicode code points; a `bytes` is a sequence of 8-bit numbers. Python 3 made the distinction between the two very clear and does not allow you to combine them implicitly. A `str` may have several valid encodings, and a `bytes` object may or may not *be* the encoding of a valid Unicode string. (Or, the `bytes` could be the encoding of multiple *different* `str` objects depending on the encoding used to create it.)

`'GET '` and `user_url` are `str` objects, while `' HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n'.encode()` is a `bytes` object. You want to encode the entire concatenated string instead.

```
cmd = 'GET {} HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n'.format(user_url).encode()
```

Or perhaps written to show the steps more clearly,

```
cmd = 'GET {} HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n'.format(user_url)  # still a str
mysock.send(cmd.encode())  # send the encoding of the str
```

Comment: Hm that doesn't work.... before: Error:`TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "bytes") to str` with this code: `cmd.send(output + output_error)` and with @chepner 's solution I have this Code: `cmd.send(output.encode() + output_error.encode())`. But then I get this error: `AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'encode'`.

Answer (score 8):

The problem is that you're encoding before concatenating:

```
'GET ' + user_url + ' HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n'.encode()
```

You have to concatenate first, and then encode the entire thing:

```
('GET ' + user_url + ' HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n').encode()
```