# encrypt-decrypt messages with python

Tags: python, encryption, fernet

I'm new to cryptography and I want to learn how can I encrypt and decrypt messages.
For example my message is this: "1234, abcd, '123CE'" will I be able to encrypt this message at once?
I tried this:

```
encryption_key = Fernet.generate_key()
fernet = Fernet(encryption_key)
encrypt_message = fernet.encrypt(message.encode())
```

but i get the error `TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "bytes") to str`

any help is appreciated, thanks.(i'm using python3 by the way)

Comment: `encrypt_message = fernet.encrypt(message)`? Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55033372/can-only-concatenate-str-not-bytes-to-str.

Comment: Not reproducible. Why do you describe the content of `message` in text instead of posting an _executable_ code?

Comment: as i said, i'm trying to learn how to do such an encryption :) first thing comes up to my mind was that code piece

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code works for me :

```py
Python 3.8.3 (default, May 19 2020, 06:50:17) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] :: Anaconda, Inc. on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import cryptography.fernet as cpf
>>> key = cpf.Fernet.generate_key()
>>> f = cpf.Fernet(key)
>>> m = f.encrypt("1234, abcd, '123CE'".encode())
>>> m
b'gAAAAABgbsGYBZjqDDilTYl5zmBfENlPkEbEdnK242_K1IBovuL-oiGrvvZmUZZMUoMQ2jYUdJ32GaI834U_Oe5Bdxhf6r-hIG5KwFawfmN45ewjSlgmzx4='
```

However, you problem can happen when generating your strings:

```py
>>> s = "my string" + b"my bytestring"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "bytes") to str
>>> s = "my string" + b"my bytestring".decode()
>>> s
'my stringmy bytestring'
```

Make sure you convert all you strings to either `str` or `bytestring` format before trying to concatenate them. For that, use :

- `s.decode()` to convert `s` to `str` if `s` is a `bytestring`
- `s.encode()` to convert `s` to `bytestring` if `s` is of `str` type.